# How to check the Online Disk Type and find Virtual Disks

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I had tried to restructured my partitions of hard drive in windows 10.But while i tried to check my online disks of hard drive , there is only one with the name of disk 0.

[image: DiskPart]

But i had more then one disks on the hard drive. As you can see

[image: drive Disks]

So currently i don't know that my remaining disks are virtual or something else.Because i tried the command

```
LIST VDISK
```

Then , it replies me that

> there are no virtual disks to show

as you can see now .

[image: disks]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partitions are not the same like disks!

Looks like you have only one harddrive but 2 partitions on it.

Try

```
LIST DISK
SELECT DISK 0
LIST PARTITION
```

Comment: THANKS FOR YOUR OPINION.I had solved the issue by checking the partitions of my drive.

Answer (score 1):

Run PowerShell command as Administrator:

```
Get-Disk | ForEach-Object { ($_ | Get-Partition)}  | ? {$_}
```

It shows number of disks and partitions.

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to use Window's **Disk Management**, with which you can see all the drives and partitions, resize, assign or reassign drive letters, mount or unmount, see how full they are, change to NTFS from FAT32, etc.  Although everything could be done from the commandline, this is much faster and less prone to making mistakes, given the choice.

I'd strongly suggest you start here:

- Control Panel
- Administrative Tools
- Computer Management
- Disk Management

You will see a graphic display of the exact layout of all the disks and partitions.  You said that you wanted to change the partition size?  This makes it very easy.